# How to format the date in dutch to dd-mm-yyyy format

Tags: php, datetime

I have a date in the format: **woensdag 22 oktober 2014 08:41:42**

I want this date to be converted to the format **dd-mm-yyyy** so that the resulting date will be 22-10-2014. The date is in dutch language.

How can I convert it using PHP

Comment: Where do you get that date? Is it inputed by users or from a database, or...? Post some code...

Comment: You need to do `str_replace` to replace the day and month names with english equivalents and then do `$date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($oldDateInEnglish));`

Comment: Yeah, this should be handled at the source. Parsing a date, like in your question, is not impossible but it is more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

I had to write a basic dictionary for it, but here it is:

```
function dutch_strtotime($datetime) {
    $days = array(
        "maandag"   => "Monday",
        "dinsdag"   => "Tuesday",
        "woensdag"  => "Wednesday",
        "donderdag" => "Thursday",
        "vrijdag"   => "Friday",
        "zaterdag"  => "Saturday",
        "zondag"    => "Sunday"
    );

    $months = array(
        "januari"   => "January",
        "februari"  => "February",
        "maart"     => "March",
        "april"     => "April",
        "mei"       => "May",
        "juni"      => "June",
        "juli"      => "July",
        "augustus"  => "August",
        "september" => "September",
        "oktober"   => "October",
        "november"  => "November",
        "december"  => "December"
    );

    $array = explode(" ", $datetime);
    $array[0] = $days[strtolower($array[0])];
    $array[2] = $months[strtolower($array[2])];
    return strtotime(implode(" ", $array));
}
$date = "woensdag 22 oktober 2014 08:41:42";
echo date("l d-m-Y H:i:s", dutch_strtotime($date)) . "<br />";
echo date("d-m-Y", dutch_strtotime($date));
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k51z-9n6j

Comment: made my jsfiddle look small i was just going to point him in the right direction +1

Comment: This was to format date for each blog post. The function is working fine but now the problem is, only one post is showing and it seems like breaking the loop of post. The site is in magento